# Any suggestions on improving this CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to find a better way to select this. Basically the `<div>` has an `id` of cat1 and it has `<a>` that has a `class` also `cat1`. Is there a better way to write this? I'm basically trying to select the `<a>` that has a similar class name as the div id it's within.

```
div#cat1 a.cat1, 
div#cat2 a.cat2, 
div#cat3 a.cat3, 
div#cat4 a.cat4 { ... }
```

Comment: Nope! That's as good as it's going to get (though it's possible that your HTML could be better set up, to make writing those selectors easier).

Comment: parent#idname div a{ stuff; }

Comment: What are you not telling here? :) This seems to be fine, although you can remove div#catX if no othe `a` has `cat1` and so on...

Comment: just wondering why should make the class of div and a the same, what's the purpose, may be there is another way if we know it.

Comment: @jerjer Actually they were initially not the same, but I thought if I do it this way, I could maybe automate it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the html that goes along with this? This looks like overkill to me.

Comment: agreed with jmohr, if we could take alook at the sample html may be we could an idea.

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is better suited to be on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the rest of your CSS, you may be able to shorten your selectors, e.g. `#cat1 .cat1, #cat2 .cat2, ...` or just `.cat1, .cat2, ...`

But I would be interested to know why you have class names such as "cat1", "cat2", etc. Could you have a single class ("cat" for lack of a better word) that all of the anchor tags could share? This could be in addition to cat1, cat2, etc. So your markup would be like:

```
<div class="cat" id="cat1"><a class="cat cat1">...</a></div>
<div class="cat" id="cat2"><a class="cat cat2">...</a></div>
```

This way you could simplify your CSS selectors for properties that apply to all of these anchors:

```
div.cat a.cat { ... }
```

But still allow the use of specific selectors such as `a.cat1` if you need to style some of these individually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the tag names.

```
#cat1 .cat1
```